# MySQl - AVG ( AVG IF) & group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I use MySQL. I have data in the following format -

```
DATE     , PAGE , PAGE_LOAD_DURATION , VISIT_TYPE
01-01-15 , A    ,                  6 , AM
01-01-15 , B    ,                  4 , PM
01-01-15 , C    ,                  5 , AM
01-01-15 , D    ,                  4 , AM
02-01-15 , B    ,                 13 , PM
03-01-15 , C    ,                 15 , PM
04-01-15 , A    ,                 17 , PM
05-01-15 , A    ,                 34 , PM
06-01-15 , B    ,                 56 , AM
07-01-15 , C    ,                 12 , AM
08-01-15 , D    ,                 89 , AM
09-01-15 , B    ,                 34 , AM
10-01-15 , R    ,                 12 , PM
11-01-15 , T    ,                 56 , AM
12-01-15 , E    ,                 78 , PM
13-01-15 , B    ,                 90 , AM
14-01-15 , A    ,                 34 , PM
15-01-15 , A    ,                 56 , AM
16-01-15 , B    ,                 23 , AM
17-01-15 , A    ,                 15 , PM
18-01-15 , R    ,                 17 , AM
19-01-15 , Y    ,                 37 , PM
20-01-15 , C    ,                 23 , AM
```

I'm trying to generate the average page load duration per page per visit type for a given date range

I'd like to generate the output in the following format -

```
PAGE, VISIT_TYPE, AVERAGE_PAGE_LOAD_DUR
A, AM, average_page_load_dur
A, PM, average_page_load_dur
B, AM, average_page_load_dur
B, PM, average_page_load_dur
C, AM, average_page_load_dur
C, PM, average_page_load_dur
D, AM, average_page_load_dur
D, PM, average_page_load_dur
so on
```

To calculate the SUM instead of average, I use the below query -

```
select
    PAGE,
    SUM(IF(VISIT_TYPE = 'AM',AVERAGE_PAGE_LOAD_DUR,0)) AS SUM_AM,
    SUM(IF(VISIT_TYPE = 'PM',AVERAGE_PAGE_LOAD_DUR,0)) AS SUM_PM
from
        PAGE_VISITS
where
    DATE >= '01-01-15' and DATE <= '09-01-15'
group by
    PAGE
```

To calcualte average, I replaced SUM with AVG, but, it looks like it is not the correct way to do as the average is being calculated as every row is scanned which doesn't make sense ( This is how I think it works. Please correct me if otherwise)

```
select
    PAGE,
    AVG(IF(VISIT_TYPE = 'AM',AVERAGE_PAGE_LOAD_DUR,0)) AS SUM_AM,
    AVG(IF(VISIT_TYPE = 'PM',AVERAGE_PAGE_LOAD_DUR,0)) AS SUM_PM
from
        PAGE_VISITS
where
    DATE >= '01-01-15' and DATE <= '09-01-15'
group by
    PAGE
```

How could I get the average to work please?

Comment: 1. Store dates as dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply leave out the `, 0`.  I prefer `case`, so I would write this as:

```
select PAGE,
       AVG(CASE WHEN VISIT_TYPE = 'AM' THEN AVERAGE_PAGE_LOAD_DUR END) AS AVG_AM,
       AVG(CASE WHEN VISIT_TYPE = 'PM' THEN AVERAGE_PAGE_LOAD_DUR END) AS AVG_PM,
from PAGE_VISITS
where DATE >= '2015-01-01' and DATE <= '2015-09-01'
group by PAGE;
```

Notes:

- `AVG()` ignores `NULL` values, but it includes `0` in the calculation.
- A column calculated as an average should probably not be called `SUM()`.
- Use ISO and MySQL standard date formats:  YYYY-MM-DD

Finally, if you are happy enough with two rows per page, then this is simpler:

```
select PAGE, AVG(AVERAGE_PAGE_LOAD_DUR) AS AVG_page_load
from PAGE_VISITS
where DATE >= '2015-01-01' and DATE <= '2015-09-01'
group by PAGE, VISIT_TYPE
```

Comment: Thank you as ever Gordon. I like the case statement. With respect to SUM, would it make sense to use   `SUM(CASE WHEN VISIT_TYPE = 'AM' THEN AVERAGE_PAGE_LOAD_DUR END) AS AVG_AM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN VISIT_TYPE = 'PM' THEN AVERAGE_PAGE_LOAD_DUR END) AS AVG_PM` instead of `SUM(IF(`

Comment: @usert4jju7 . . . Yes, `SUM()` works instead of `AVG()`.  With `SUM()`, though, including `ELSE 0` makes sense, so the result is never `NULL`.